Punctured neighbourhood of quotient singularity is not simply connected?
Let $X$ be a variety (irreducible, normal) over a field $k$ which is algebraically closed with characteristic $0$. Suppose that $X$ has only one singular point $p\in X$, so $Y:=X\setminus p$ is smooth.

If $p$ is a quotient singularity, then is $Y$ not simply connected?

To be clear, by quotient singularity I mean that $p$ has an étale neighbourhood of the form $W/F$ where $W$ is a smooth variety and $F$ is a finite group (I think we can just assume that $W$ is affine space over $k$ and $F$ acts linearly, so the singularity is coming from the origin in $W$).
For example, if $X$ is the affine variety $\{xy=z^2\}$, then the origin is a quotient singularity, and $\pi_1(Y)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so the answer to my question is yes in this simple example.
The answer to another question I asked seems to imply that if $p$ is a quotient singularity then there is some punctured étale neighbourhood of $p$ which is not simply connected. But I want to be able to say that $Y$ specifically is not simply connected.
(if it helps, in the situation I care about $X$ is affine with an action by a connected reductive $G$, and $Y$ can be written as $G/H$ for a connected $H$, but I will avoid assuming this here if possible to have more generality).

Just to clarify: are you assuming that $F$ acts freely on $W$ except for the orbit over the unique singular point?

Anyway, the answer is still "no."  Consider the action of the cyclic group of order $2$, $\langle g | g^2 \rangle$,  on the complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^2 = \text{Proj}\ \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ by $g\cdot [x,y,z] = [-x,-y,z]$.  The quotient variety is the singular quadric cone $\text{Zero}(su-t^2)$ inside $\mathbb{CP}^3 = \text{Proj} \ \mathbb{C}[s,t,u,v]$, where $s$ is $x^2$, where $t$ is $xy$, where $u$ is $y^2$, and where $v$ is $z^2$.  The complement of the unique singular point is a rank $1$ complex vector bundle over a smooth plane conic, and this is simply connected.

@JasonStarr that's a good question. My understanding is that we can assume $W=\mathbb{A}^n$ and that $F$ acts linearly, so because it's characteristic $0$ and there is the unique singularity (so isolated), it should necessarily be the case the $F$ acts freely on $W$ away from the origin. Like in section 2.1 of this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3149 (Lemma 2.4). But maybe I'm interpreting this incorrectly.

Just to reconcile this with your example: if you remove the zero section from that rank $1$ complex vector bundle, then that is non-simply connected, and that gives a (Zariski) open deleted neighborhood of the singular point that is not simply connected.  However, when you glue in the zero section, that "kills" the fundamental group.

@JasonStarr thanks for the example. I'll need to think of something that works in my specific situation. But if you want to post this example as an answer I can accept it, up to you.

I have not posted my comment as an answer, because I am still trying to solve the modified question.  In that case, you may be able to use homogeneity under the action of $G$ to get what you want . . .
